# Obtain ordered vertices of GeneralPath

Tags: java, geometry, 2d

How can I obtain the vertices of a GeneralPath object? It seems like this should be possible, since the path is constructed from points (lineTo, curveTo, etc).

I'm trying to create a double[][] of point data (an array of x/y coordinates).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the points back from the `PathIterator`.

I'm not sure what your constraints are, but if your shape always has just one closed subpath and has only straight edges (no curves) then the following will work:

```
static double[][] getPoints(Path2D path) {
    List<double[]> pointList = new ArrayList<double[]>();
    double[] coords = new double[6];
    int numSubPaths = 0;
    for (PathIterator pi = path.getPathIterator(null);
         ! pi.isDone();
         pi.next()) {
        switch (pi.currentSegment(coords)) {
        case PathIterator.SEG_MOVETO:
            pointList.add(Arrays.copyOf(coords, 2));
            ++ numSubPaths;
            break;
        case PathIterator.SEG_LINETO:
            pointList.add(Arrays.copyOf(coords, 2));
            break;
        case PathIterator.SEG_CLOSE:
            if (numSubPaths > 1) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Path contains multiple subpaths");
            }
            return pointList.toArray(new double[pointList.size()][]);
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Path contains curves");
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unclosed path");
}
```

If your path may contain curves, you can use [the flattening version of `getPathIterator()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Path2D.html#getPathIterator%28java.awt.geom.AffineTransform,%20double%29).

Answer (score 0):

I'd doubt if it is always possible, if at all... JavaDoc says:

> "The GeneralPath class represents a
>   geometric path constructed from
>   straight lines, and quadratic and
>   cubic (Bézier) curves."

So if it is a curve, the points it'd contain not necessarily are part of a curve.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i looked for, i didn't find any answer to  : " how to extract summit of an Area, or GeneralPath either".

I can extract a bunch of segments. even a triangle area return more than 3 segments with this method.

```
while (!i.isDone()) {
   float[] coords = new float[2];
   int segType = i.currentSegment(coords);
   if (segType != PathIterator.SEG_CLOSE) {
      list.add(coords);
   }
   i.next();
}

return list;
```